# Allowing for multiple conditions if a checkbox=checked?

Tags: javascript

New to Javascript, teaching myself for fun.  I have a basic function, and what  I am attempting to do is make a checkbox (if checked) do more than one thing.  In this example, I want to make a form become visible and also make the inputs required.

What I am noticing is that the first line works, I can make the form appear.  However, the first input in that form does not become required.

Here is the Function.

When the checkbox is checked, the function does work.  It makes the form "kForm2" become visible and hides it if not checked.  But it seems it doesnt want to run the second line, where i require the first input of that form. There is also about 10 more inputs that I want to make required if that checkbox is checked.  I know im writing this wrong, but I cant find the information online.  Thanks

```
<input type="checkbox" id="k2Check"  onclick="k2()">

<div id="kForm2" style="display:none">
    <label for="kfirstname2">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="kfirstname2" id="kfirstname2" 
    minlength="3" maxlength="20">
</div>

    <script>
        function k2() {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("k2Check");
    var kForm2 = document.getElementById("kForm2");
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
       kForm2.style.display = "block"; 
       this.getField(kfirstname2).required=true;
    } 
    else {
        kForm2.style.display = "none";
        this.getField(kfirstname2).required=false;
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: one time you pass `kfirstname2` as a variable, the other `"kfirstname2"` as a string - which one is correct?

Comment: VLAZ, it is meant to be a var.  Thank you for noticing that.  It is meant to call the ID i had set for the input which is id="kfirstname2".  I have edited the original post as well.

Comment: So where does that variable get a value in your code? `onclick="kid2()"` and `function k2()` don’t match either. Please provide a proper example that doesn’t brim with such inconsistencies.

Comment: Hey Peter, I have included the html, and the js function.  I hope this helps, as that sits it will properly display the form kForm2.  However, it then skips the next condition where I attempt to get the input kfirstname2 to become required.  Im assuming my function doesn't allow for multiple executions based on that one conditon?

Comment: Sorry misorude, i was attempting to shorten the code as to ease this for you guys.  It has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong code, after further research.

```
INCORRECT
this.getField(kfirstname2).required=true;

CORRECT
document.getElementById("kfirstname2").required = true;
```

This is working now thanks for your help guys.